# Can't Enable Bitlocker

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, bitlocker, tpm, windows-storage-server

[image]
[image]

### Why not?!

How can I find out why not?

I recently enabled Bitlocker without TPM in our domain controller:

[image]

## Update

Thanks to Greg's 2nd comment I've discovered that I need a basic disk:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bdehdcfg -driveinfo
BitLocker Drive Preparation Tool version 6.3.9600
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Initializing, please wait...

BitLocker Setup requires a basic disk. Convert your dynamic disk to a basic
disk and run BitLocker Setup again.
```

This could be problematic in my case:

[image]

This machine is a Buffalo Terastation - WS5000R2 series.

Comment: Try it from the command line, and post any messages here.  `manage-bde -on C: -RecoveryPassword -StartupKey x:` where x: is the drive where you want to store the startup key.  If you want to store the startup key on the Recovery partition, you will need to temporarily map a drive letter to it.

Comment: Also, probably should go without saying, you need to have a valid recovery partition.  You can run `bdehdcfg -driveinfo` for more information.

Comment: A clue from your second suggestion: `BitLocker Setup requires a basic disk. Convert your dynamic disk to a basic
disk and run BitLocker Setup again.`

Comment: See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Buffalo should do a better job disclosing that product does not provide any encryption capability (or use disks with builtin hardware encryption for at-rest encryption).  I think the solution here would be to acquire another appliance that has encryption and return the Buffalo WSS appliance.